# Release uses an old version of Google Play Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've been searching for hours but I can't seem to find an answer to what is the difference between `Google Play Billing Library` and `In-app Billing API` and if one of them is causing the error message below:

```
Release uses an old version of Google Play Billing
```

I'm reading about `Google Play Billing Library` here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate and the `In-app Billing API` here: http://android.cn-mirrors.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

I'm really confused, the whole confusion started because I was trying to deploy an old app on Google play started by someone else long ago, but got the error:

```
Release uses an old version of Google Play Billing
```

So I started to look at what version of the billing library the app uses but I couldn't find it. From the `AndroidManifest.xml`, I see:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

And from one of the files in the android project I see:

```
import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
```

As you can see it doesn't really tell me what version the library is.

Having no experience in Google play store, I started looking up `Google Play Billing Library` and I'm seeing:

```
To be compliant, apps must import version 4.0.0 or higher of the Play Billing Library. Note that Billing dependencies would be found only in APKs that require the com.android.vending.BILLING permission.
```

Problem is I'm not seeing anything that's importing the `Google Play Billing Library` dependency in the project, ie:

```
dependencies {
    def billing_version = "5.0.0"

    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"
}
```

This makes me thing, perhaps the project is not using the Google Play Billing Library at all.

So I started to look at `IInAppBillingService` which led me here: http://android.cn-mirrors.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html. This seems to be an old library? Which is making me think that's the reason why I'm getting `Release uses an old version of Google Play Billing` when I'm trying to deploy the app.

This leads me to my question:

1. Am I getting the error `Release uses an old version of Google Play Billing` because the project is using `IInAppBillingService` which is very old?
2. What is the difference between `Google Play Billing Library` and `In-app Billing API`.

Answer (score -1):

`IInAppBillingService.aidl` is obsolete and might not even be considered anymore.
What the difference in between the [library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) and the [API](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) is, should possibly be obvious.